# Android Studio Calling new methods on older versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After Updating to Android Studio 0.2.13 I have a big amount of lint problems with API Errors (`Calling new methods on older versions`).
One example from thousands:

[image]
[image]

I taught that the min sdk is read out from the manifest.xml?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Ive tried to set it in the grandle build but this didnt helped.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 5
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Try to reopen Android studio, close project and then close studio and then open studio and open project. It's helped me.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried, didnt helped :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the compile version set?:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 10
       targetSdkVersion 18
    }
```

UPDATE:

Also, this always helped with tricky situations like this.
Close the project, go into the project folder and delete .iml in all the projects, and the hidden .idea folder. Then re-import the project.
And remember to point to the build.gradle file and not the folder project, since the gradle files will not be picked up by the Android Studio otherwise.

This should fix it.

Comment: Yes its set with `buildToolsVersion "18.1"`

Comment: Update made it. I used ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew assembleRelease after added defaultConfig to gradle

Comment: so the `minSdkVersion` in grandle will be used instead of  `android:minSdkVersion"` in the Manifest??

Comment: When compiling and for IDE purposes it will.